# How to connect Windows Phone for multiplayer game using local wifi,internet or bluetooth

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, multiplayer

I am trying to develop a real time multiplayer game which can be played over local WiFi,Bluetooth or over internet. 
I have searched a lot about it on internet but was not able to find anything to start with.I found one sample rock paper scissors but i think it only works with Bluetooth and range of NFC is too low.
So can anyone please direct me to right right direction. I looked into WiFi direct also but i think its only available for windows 8.

Comment: You'll have to look in to different solutions for different networks (Bluetooth/LAN/Internet etc.). I can recommend appwarp for online (internet) game play across devices. There are samples for windows phone available here - http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/windows-game-developers-home/

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bound by having to use a local connectivity system (Local wifi, bluetooth, NFC), I think it would be easier to focus on using internet.
According to the kind of game you want to build, you might think of either using peer to peer sockets ( this might be a good starting point: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickyt/archive/2011/06/15/windows-phone-peer-to-peer-multiplayer-game-using-sockets-in-xna.aspx ) or if you want a game in which several players interact, you might considering using a client-server architecture, and there is a broad array of resources available for that.